# Does having a site devoted to entirely different topics effect SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, google, ranking, google-ranking

I have my website divided into several sub-folders i.e

```
www.mysite.com/dogs

www.mysite.com/cats

www.mysite.com/submarines

www.mysite.com/art

.
.
.
```

Each with different layout and high quality content and none of the sub folders link to other sub-folders.

My questions is: Does having a site like this devoted to entirely different topics effect SEO ranking?

Comment: How awesome is this. I was looking for this answer last night and just found it posted today. Its basically the same as sites like Amazon, Best Buy, etc...they have tons of products and they rank pretty well. Yes they are very well known sites with a huge amount of link backs but still you shouldn't have to build different sites per domain to have a successful ranking site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit or harm from doing this as each page is judged on its own merit. This would be no different if you used a subdomain for each topic (or even gave them all each their own domain).

e.g.

```
dogs.mysite.com
cats.mysite.com
```

Comment: thank John Conde for response. I heard that google prefers sites that are devoted to one topic or niche, is this true, do they rank better?

Comment: It's not true. Having one topic per site is the norm but not a requirement for good SEO. It might be more user-friendly and easier to market if you had different domians, though.

Comment: By "easier to market" do you mean on site advertisement?

Comment: I mean by having a custom domain you could more easily brand it and such.